# Regex on version format in Jenkins Validating String Parameter Plugin

Tags: regex, bash, jenkins

I'm using the [Validating String Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Validating+String+Parameter+Plugin?focusedCommentId=42469253). Now I can define some regex pattern for the input of my parameter.
I want to allow the pattern:

```
NUMBER.NUMBER.NUMBER
```

Examples are:

```
11.2.4
5.0.88
0.8.7
128.1518.4848
```

What I don't allow are things like

```
2.4
2.4.1e
..
```

So just 3 times all the possible numbers with two dots between them.
How can I define this in a regex?

I tried: `^[0-9]+$.^[0-9]+$.^[0-9]+$` but it didn't work.

Comment: Remove anchors inside the pattern - `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -P '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$' inputfile
11.2.4
5.0.88
0.8.7
128.1518.4848
```

Comment: Cool, very efficient. I'll approve the answer in a few minutes